# How to correctly save predictions made with Rastervision?

Tags: python, deep-learning, geospatial, semantic-segmentation

I was able to make my first complete semantic segmentation pipeline using Rastervision ([RV](https://rastervision.io)) as a module. I made the code on this Kaggle [notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/luizclaudioandrade/rastervision-101) with this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/luizclaudioandrade/naip-chesapeake-sample).

The predictions are ok for the validation dataset (considering the number os epochs used), but when I use my learner to generate the predictions for my prediction dataset:

```
from rastervision.core.data import SemanticSegmentationLabels

predictions = learner.predict_dataset(
    dataset=prediction_dataset,
    raw_out=True,
    numpy_out=True,
    predict_kw=dict(out_shape=IMG_SIZE), # using 256x256
    progress_bar=True,
)

pred_labels = SemanticSegmentationLabels.from_predictions(
    windows=prediction_dataset.windows,
    predictions=predictions,
    smooth=True, # trying both outputs
    extent=prediction_dataset.scene.extent,
    num_classes=len(class_config),
)
```

The results are not good. What am I doing wrong?

Here are the predictions for my validation dataset:
[image]

And here are the geotif file saved with:

```
pred_labels.save(
    uri=os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'predictions'),
    crs_transformer=prediction_dataset.scene.raster_source.crs_transformer,
    class_config=class_config,
)
```

On the left we have the labels for the window displayed and on the right we have the same window on the geotiff saved.
[image]

What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I've got help from the official discussion at Azavea's GitHub [here](https://github.com/azavea/raster-vision/discussions/1810).

The problem was that I wasn't loading my learner in prediction mode. I need to do:

```
bundle_uri = os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'model-bundle.zip')
predictlearner = SemanticSegmentationLearner.from_model_bundle(
    model_bundle_uri=bundle_uri,
    training=False,
    output_dir=OUTPUT_DIR,
)
```

Doing this before the predictions solves the problem.